# How to activate lost mode on iCloud for iPhone that cannot be located?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

I lost my phone in a taxi just after landing at an airport. My phone was in airplane mode and I cannot locate it with iCloud. On iCloud help pages, it says I can turn on the lost mode.

I tried:

- Locate my phone, wait for it to fail. No menu appeared to ask if I wanted to lock it
- Go in Settings -> my iPhone. I clicked on "lost your phone ? ...? " which did nothing but bring me to a help page

Is that normal ? I'm using Ubuntu/Chrome if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to iCloud, go to [Find My iPhone](https://www.icloud.com/#find), select your phone in the drop down list on the top of the page, provided it has Find My iPhone enabled it should show up as offline. [Lost mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT88N.jpg) should be available.

Comment: thanks but I ask because "Lost mode" is not available... can you see it on your computer ? (if you turn your phone on airplane mode)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did to take the [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mT88N.jpg).

Comment: For users who struggle : on the page "no device detected", click on "list of my devices" and even if your mouse looks like an arrow and not a clickable pointer, select your iphone and wait a bit, you will then have the screen

Answer (score 0):

Airplane Mode disables *any* cellular service and wifi. You can only hope that the person who finds the iPhone will turn off Airplane Mode, and the iPhone will reconnect to cellular service. The iCloud server will then 'see' the iPhone and set it into Lost mode. Until Airplane Mode is disabled, you are out of luck.

In addition, you will have had to deliberately configured your iPhone to use Find My iPhone. If you did not enable this feature, you are well and truly out of luck.